# How to perform filtering for an observable loading data from a server using a form control using rxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am trying to filter a list using rxJS and the list is not properly filtered unless I explicitly force the form to emit a first value. This is my code:

```
this.store.dispatch(new AllTagsRequestedAction());
this.tags$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectAllTags));

this.filteredTags$ = this.tagsForm.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith({ partialSearch: "" }),
  withLatestFrom(this.tags$),
  switchMap(([formVal, tags]: [{ partialSearch: string}, TagModel[]]) => {
    console.log("Tags and form val: ", tags, formVal);
    const filteredTags = tags.filter(t => !formVal.partialSearch || t.name.includes(formVal.partialSearch));
    return of(filteredTags);
  })
);

// this is really ugly, but it seem to work
this.tags$.subscribe(tags => {
  if (tags && tags.length > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.tagsForm.setValue({ partialSearch: "q"});
    });
  }
});
```

Console confirms that `tags` is empty at the beginning and only the timeout triggers the values being filtered.

I understand that the issue is related to getting the latest value from `$tags` as an empty list (not yet loaded from back-end), but I do not know how to fix this.

Question: How to perform filtering for an observable loading data from a server using a form control using rxJS?

Comment: try create the observable this.tagsForm.valueChanges in a pipe tap of this.tags$, some like `this.tags$=this.store.pipe(select(selectAllTags),tap(()=>this.filteredTags=this.tagsForm.valueChanges.pipe(....))`: NOTE I prefer `const filteredTags=formVale.partialSearch?tags.filter(t=>...):tags` to avoid extra comparaison

Comment: Where is `filteredTags$` subscribed to? Is it displayed in the template with the `async` pipe? Nothing should happen if it's not subscribed to.

Comment: @PatrickStephansen - no, besides the initial value, it works because I subscribe via the async pipe. `Eliseo` is right, I will try implementing using the hint in the comment.

Comment: @Eliseo - you are right. I have managed to get it working. You should consider promoting your comment as an answer. If you do not have the time, I will post my working solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const tagForm$ = this.tagsForm.valueChanges.pipe(startWith({ partialSearch: "" }));
const tags$ =  this.store.pipe(select(selectAllTags));

this.filteredTags$ = combineLatest(tagForm$, tags$).pipe(
  map(([formVal, tags]: [{ partialSearch: string}, TagModel[]]) => {
    const filteredTags = tags.filter(t => !formVal.partialSearch || t.name.includes(formVal.partialSearch));
    return filteredTags;
  })
);
```

you want `combinelatest` and `map`.

`combinelatest` will emit every time either stream emits (but not until both have at least once).

`switchMap` is a waste, use `map` for a synchronous transform.

Comment: It is a very good alternative to my working solution. Also, replacing `switchMap` with `map` makes perfect sense and it also works in my initial code. Thanks.

Comment: I have replaced the code with my fully working code, so that it can be directly usable in the future. Hope it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `combineLatest` with `filter` operator like this:

```
this.store.dispatch(new AllTagsRequestedAction());

this.filteredTags$ = combineLatest([
                            this.tagsForm.valueChanges.pipe(
                                                            startWith({ partialSearch: "" })
                                                           ),
                            this.store.pipe(
                                              select(selectAllTags),
                                              filter(tags => !!tags)
                                           )
                         ]).pipe(
                           switchMap(([formVal, tags]: [{ partialSearch: string}, TagModel[]]) => {
                              console.log("Tags and form val: ", tags, formVal);
                              const filteredTags = tags.filter(t => !formVal.partialSearch || t.name.includes(formVal.partialSearch));
                              return of(filteredTags);
                            }
                           )
                         );
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator?

Usage example:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit (1,2,3,4,5)
const source = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
//filter out non-even numbers
const example = source.pipe(filter(num => num % 2 === 0));
//output: "Even number: 2", "Even number: 4"
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(`Even number: ${val}`));
```

Comment: Not sure if it helps here. I have tried to get filteredTag$ based on form values emitted values which works fine except for the beginning when the tag$ which emits a single value after a while. My issue seems more related to how to correctly combine those observables than filtering.